# How to know when iTunes has finished copying a file to the documents directory

Tags: ios

I've got file sharing working in my app and am monitoring the documents directory to see when new files are added, using Apple's DirectoryWatcher code.  At the point this triggers I'd like to be able to read the new file to extract a few bits of information, but if I do this immediately then iTunes can still be copying the file over and the read fails.  I can get around this by polling the file until it succeeds, but I was wondering if there is a better way.  Is it possible to trigger an event when iTunes has finished copying?

**Update:** I've read the other question and answer and I can see how that could help, but there's one thing that seems to be missing.  There doesn't seem to be a way to tell if it's necessary to call that code.  There are two possibilities, one is the one I'm coming up against, that iTunes hasn't finished copying, in which case calling that code would tell me when it has finished.  The other possibility is that iTunes has finished copying by the time I try to read the file, in which case the events that that code is trying to catch have already happened, so it would be pointless to call it.  The problem now becomes, how to tell whether I need to call that code?

Comment: The only solution I've found is to wait to be notified of the directory change then poll the file looking for changes in file size. If the last two or three changes show the same size, I assume it is done. Make sure you test with the device connected via WiFi too, not just a cable. I wish there was a better way.

Comment: Interesting find.  I'll have to have a close look at that.